# Как скрыть браузер chrome при тестах Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, как скрыть браузер при запусках теста на selenium c#? В качестве браузера использую браузер хром и версию Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0. Консоль скрыта с помощью такого куска кода.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                
web = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
webtwo = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
```

Comment: [Can Selenium WebDriver open browser windows silently in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16180428/312041)

Answer (score 0):

Скрыла консоль и браузер с помощью такого кода

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--window-position=-32000,-32000");

web = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
webtwo = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```